# Pick random number from stored procedure without equating

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE person 
( 
    pid INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    pname varchar(50), 
    page int, 
    psalary int, 
    paddress varchar(50) 
)
```

This is my procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testalready
    @createid int,
    @createname varchar(50) = NULL,
    @crage int 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @already varchar(50)

    SELECT @already = FLOOR(RAND() * POWER(CAST(10 AS BIGINT), 5))

    INSERT INTO person (pid, pname, page, psalary)
    VALUES (@createid, @createname, @crage, @already)
END
```

Now is there any such command/method or way to execute my procedure `testalready` that `@createname` takes the value generated by `@already`.

I know I can write `@createname = @already` but actually I am not allowed to change anything in the procedure. It is some sort of my limitation. Just by somehow writing any such command which somehow picks the value from procedure and then assigns it to `@createname`.

Thank you

Comment: There is no `@randno` anywhere in your code. I assume you're asking if you can access local variables from outside. I'm pretty sure you cannot.

Comment: you can try to sniff out the last inserted person and get the psalary from it. But this is very bad, if you can't change the procedure, ask someone else to change it

Answer (score 0):

You need only generate your random number  an use it

```
create table person ( pid INT primary key, pname varchar(50), page int , psalary int, paddress varchar(50) )
```

```
CREATE procedure testalready
@createid int ,
@createname varchar(50) = NULL,
@crage int 
as
begin 
declare @already varchar(50)
SELECT @already=FLOOR(RAND()*POWER(CAST(10 as BIGINT), 5))

insert into person (pid,pname,page,psalary)
values (@createid,@createname,@crage,@already)

end
```

```
DECLARE @randno BIGINT;
Set @randno = (SELECT CAST(ROUND((RAND() - .5) * 2147483647, 0) AS BIGINT));

EXEC testalready 1,@randno,1
```

```
1 rows affected
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n-TghuYA)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [INSTEAD OF insert trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and intercept (essentially rewrite) the `INSERT` statement so, that the value supplied for the `psalary` column is inserted into the `pname` column as well.

Though, the trigger will intercept **all** `INSERT` statements, not only this one that is caused by this procedure.